# ElasticSearch: apply filter on top of user provided query in NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

A user can use a dedicated endpoint to pass in queries. He has the freedom to specify any query and filter for all fields. But before the endpoint redirects the search request to the Elasticsearch server I would like to apply another filter on top to restrict access to only a specific set of results. You can think of this as an authorization filter: User X can only access objects that are linked to his user ID.

I started with an endpoint accepting war queries:

```
        var query = "{\"match\":{\"firstname\":\"John\"}}"
        var searchResponse = await _client.SearchAsync<users>(s => s
            .From(0)
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q =>
                q.Raw(query))
        );
```

Is there a way to modify the filter of this query to restrict access of this call? Or maybe there is even a smarter way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to automatically apply filters to search requests, you can use [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) to do so. Please bear in mind however, that filtered aliases are not a comprehensive feature for authorization.